# CSS, images and scripts not loading in chrome

Tags: php, wordpress, google-chrome

Good day all,

My site http://mothercitydesigns.com looks good on all browsers except latest version of chrome canary version 45. None of my css, images or scripts are loading.

Looking at developer tools it seems that they are being linked using

```
https://
```

instead of just

```
http://
```

This is a concern as I dont have an ssl certificate and my wp general site settings are set to display

```
http://mothercitydesigns.com
```

I've contacted my host and they recon its not a server issue.

Any ideas?

Comment: as you already know some of the links on your website have https:// , then it has to be changed , so that the website works normally.

Comment: Are they also being linked using "https://" in the browsers where it is working? Currently researching the problem to see if I can recreate it, but I must say your site looks pretty damn awesome.

Comment: Hi Chandu, you're not understanding. Refer to Suman Barick's comment:     Are they also being linked using "https://" in the browsers where it is working?  No, Suman, the working browsers link using http://.   By the way its Google Canary v. 45 that links with https://.

Comment: And thanks Suman Barick

Comment: You are welcome :) 
Looks like an issue with Chrome canary. found this https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=350912

And if really that's the case, then there is nothing much to do from our side, I guess, other than waiting for them to fix it. :P

Comment: Great, thank you. I was really worried about whether I was doing something wrong. Hopefully they fix it in the next update

Comment: That bug report is entirely un-related. The site in question there specifically enabled *HSTS* headers to tell clients to cache their SSL info and always connect with that. Then it was turned off, but because of the cache Chrome continued to connect with HTTPS (as it should.) See my answer to get the details on what is *most likely* occurring in your case and what you can do about it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is most likely related to a known issue with introducing the HTTPS upgrade header (HTTPS:1). Some wordpress and Joomla (most likely others as well) are seeing this as "Make all the URLs HTTPS period" when they shouldn't. A bug is open in the Chromium tracker and discussion is ongoing in the standards body as far as how to handle renaming the header. Until then, you should disable extensions slowly to find the one causing it, and then keep it disabled. Or fix the problem in the extension and submit a patch back to the writers so others can get the update as well.

Update:

Looking at the output closer, somewhere to look at is with whatever is generating the following part of your `<head>`

```html
<script type='text/javascript' src='https://www.mothercitydesigns.com/wp-includes/js/jquery/ui/jquery.ui.core.min.js?ver=1.10.4'></script>
<script type='text/javascript' src='https://www.mothercitydesigns.com/wp-includes/js/jquery/ui/jquery.ui.widget.min.js?ver=1.10.4'></script>
<script type='text/javascript' src='https://www.mothercitydesigns.com/wp-includes/js/jquery/ui/jquery.ui.mouse.min.js?ver=1.10.4'></script>
<script type='text/javascript' src='https://www.mothercitydesigns.com/wp-includes/js/jquery/ui/jquery.ui.slider.min.js?ver=1.10.4'></script>


<script type='text/javascript' src='http://www.mothercitydesigns.com/wp-content/plugins/woocommerce-currency-switcher/js/price-slider.js?ver=4.0.5'></script>
<script type='text/javascript' src='http://www.mothercitydesigns.com/wp-content/plugins/woocommerce-currency-switcher/js/front.js?ver=4.0.5'></script>


<script type='text/javascript' src='https://www.mothercitydesigns.com/wp-content/plugins/owl-carousel/js/owl.carousel.js?ver=4.0.5'></script>
<script type='text/javascript' src='https://www.mothercitydesigns.com/wp-content/plugins/owl-carousel/js/script.js?ver=4.0.5'></script>
<link rel="EditURI" type="application/rsd+xml" title="RSD" href="https://www.mothercitydesigns.com/xmlrpc.php?rsd" />
<link rel="wlwmanifest" type="application/wlwmanifest+xml" href="https://www.mothercitydesigns.com/wp-includes/wlwmanifest.xml" />
```

There are two scripts (extra space around them) that are called with HTTP where the other resources highlighted are called with HTTPS. I'd check and see how all of these are being generated. Looks like woocommerce is directly injecting or using a custom method when the others are referencing the same method. If I'm right, then that method is what is causing issues (probably by misinterpreting the new header.)

Comment: Thanks for the advice Garbee. I've done what you suggested, It doesn't look like a plugin is doing it. Is it possible that it could be the actual CSS and js files? On Google pagespeed insights i get warnings to minify js and css - render blocking js and css.

Comment: Pagespeed is a good thing to keep an eye on, but that has nothing to do with security problems. Updating answer with more detail of what to look at for better formatting.

Comment: You're absolutely right. It is the woocommerce plugin. I didnt expect that. However they aren't being called from the head area.

Comment: Out of interrest, how were you able to establish that woocommerce was the problem from looking at the .js links?

Comment: Seeing the paths helps a lot when they are named like this. It didn't look like woocommerce directly was the problem but other things (since the woocommerce plugins were called via HTTP as they should be, but others were HTTPS.) Just something you pick up debugging so much stuff over years. Whether the items were being put into the head directly or injected via an event, starting there in your source code would lead you down the tree of your own code to debug.

Answer (score 0):

After reading the WooCommerce changelog, version 2.3.12 says:

2.3.12 - 06/07/2015

```
Fix - Fixed Google Chrome forcing to use SSL. This can cause some issues on websites behind load balancers or reverse proxies.
```

Have just done a database backup and updated woocommerce.

Seems to have fixed the problem.

*Although, I've had problems implemeting my woocommerce child theme so changes i'd make to the core woocommerce installation need updating. So, I've gone bak to the previous version until I get the chil theme up and running properly.*